# Binding StackPanel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My goal is to have the entire top StackPanel (or some other element) open a website using the `Url` value from the XML data that's being returned. I was wondering what would be the best way to achieve this?

Here is a sample of my XAML code:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel> //bind Url here somehow
        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"></Image>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Stats}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is a sample of the values my code behind is returning:

```
    public class XmlData
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string Stats { get; set; }
        public double Duration { get; set; }
    }
```

Code examples appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xaml:

```
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel MouseLeftButtonDown="StackPanelMouseLeftButtonDown" Tag="{Binding Url}">
        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"></Image>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Stats}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

code behind:

```
private void StackPanelMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    var realSender = (StackPanel)sender;
    WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
    wbt.URL = (string)realSender.Tag;
    wbt.Show(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. This code did not work for me. I would get an error when I would click on the StackPanel. Is there perhaps something missing?

Comment: @crazymatt the code given is correct and works. I suggest you run through a few WP7 / Silverlight tutorials then try it again,

Comment: Does the error appear on NavigationService.Navigate part?
If that happens can you show us what's the value of your Url string.

Comment: Yes I get an error: 

"Navigation is only supported to relative URIs that are fragments, or being with '/', or which contain ';component/'. Parameter name: uri."

Comment: So what's the value of your Url?

Comment: I am passing a URL to Vimeo. So it looks something like http://vimeo.com/m/videoID I have tested this with HyperLinkButton and it works so it seems that the URLs are valid.

Comment: OK I was able to get it to work using code from your example above and using WebBrowserTask. Here's what I ended up with in case anyone else runs into this issue:

`private void StackPanelMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var realSender = (StackPanel)sender;
    WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
    wbt.URL = (string)realSender.Tag;
    wbt.Show();
}`

Answer (score 1):

A stackpanel cannot open a URL itself, you'll need a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control for this.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <WebBrowser Source="{Binding Url}" />
        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"></Image>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Stats}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Sorry if my question was misleading but I do not want to open the URL in a Web Browser in my app. I want to be able to click anywhere in that top StackPanel and have it externally open the Windows Phone IE Browser to the appropriate website.